# css overflow messes with screen width

Tags: css, overflow, width, screen

I'm making a modal where the show modal button when clicked will display the modal right in the middle of the screen and has the exact same width as the main page. but the modal is not as right in the middle as I expected. I think it's because of the overflow style which adds scroll on the right side. how do I solve this?

```
<body>
    <main>
      <h1>THIS IS MAIN PAGE</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
        mollitia, repellendus, ratione modi saepe iste ea id qui quia autem nisi
        distinctio maxime! Repellat, consequatur. Possimus delectus perferendis,
        illo vero perspiciatis tenetur debitis provident itaque rem laborum sint
        esse temporibus officia reprehenderit nesciunt laudantium, aspernatur
        consectetur quia sapiente exercitationem odit. Molestiae necessitatibus,
        dolorem illum expedita minus obcaecati dicta distinctio minima?
      </p>
      <button>show modal</button>
    </main>
    <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <h2>THIS IS MODAL PAGE</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi
          nobis nulla iure consequuntur provident? Laborum, suscipit. Aut
          similique dolor unde tempora laborum voluptates at cupiditate,
          deserunt voluptate illum cum explicabo magnam quibusdam quam facere
          consectetur aspernatur adipisci. Magnam, inventore harum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", ()=> document.querySelector(".modal-container").classList.add("show"));
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  width: min(calc(100% - 3.125rem), 45.625rem);
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
  background-color: aqua;
}
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  padding: 20vh 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 200ms;
}
.modal-container.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-wrapper {
  width: min(calc(100% - 3.125rem), 45.625rem);
  height: 150vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1.75rem 1.25rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 200ms;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised example (scroll and centered).
We didn't have the JS 'close' script so that part is left as provided.
There are a few CSS lines we turned off to resolve the issue, and a few of those lines can be switched back on if needed for you main content. Non-scrollable text in popup will need minor further CSS changes.

```js
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", ()=> document.querySelector(".modal-container").classList.add("show"));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
/*--  xwidth: min(calc(100% - 0.1rem), 45.625rem); --*/
  height: 80vh;
  position: relative;
/*--  xleft: 25%; --*/
/*--  xtransform: translate(-0%, -0%); --*/
  background-color: aqua;
}
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
/*--  xinset: 0; --*/
/*--  xpadding: 20vh 0; --*/
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
/*--  xoverflow: scroll; --*/
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 200ms;
  /*--add all below--*/
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-container.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-wrapper {
/*--  width: min(calc(100% - 3.125rem), 45.625rem); --*/
/*--  height: 150vh; --*/
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1.75rem 1.25rem;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: 200ms;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  /*--add all below--*/
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; 
}
```

```html
<main>
      <h1>THIS IS MAIN PAGE</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
        mollitia, repellendus, ratione modi saepe iste ea id qui quia autem nisi
        distinctio maxime! Repellat, consequatur. Possimus delectus perferendis,
        illo vero perspiciatis tenetur debitis provident itaque rem laborum sint
        esse temporibus officia reprehenderit nesciunt laudantium, aspernatur
        consectetur quia sapiente exercitationem odit. Molestiae necessitatibus,
        dolorem illum expedita minus obcaecati dicta distinctio minima?
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <button>show modal centered</button> 
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <button id="myBtn">W3 Open Modal</button>
    </main>
    
    <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <h2>THIS IS MODAL PAGE</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi
          nobis nulla iure consequuntur provident? Laborum, suscipit. Aut
          similique dolor unde tempora laborum voluptates at cupiditate,
          deserunt voluptate illum cum explicabo magnam quibusdam quam facere
          consectetur aspernatur adipisci. Magnam, inventore harum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a good explanation and examples of an absolute centered modal:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/kOxGQa?editors=1100)